# css - fontello spinner image css integration

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, css, fontello

I am having a background image defined in css and I want to replace with another fontello spinner image class.
How can I do this?

```css
#divOverLay.show {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0);
    background-image: url('../images/spinner_blue.gif');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
}
```

The fontello class which I want to release is below 
(this is to replace the above background-image):

```
"demo-icon icon-arrows-ccw"
```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure I understand your question, but you want to change css class?

If so, use the [jQuery css()](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_css.asp) method

```
$('#divOverLay.show').attr('class', 'demo-icon icon-arrows-ccw');
```

Comment: This is OK . Its better if we are able to define in the css itself.

Comment: Do what in css exactly? You added `jQuery` and `javascript` tag in post, but you don't want JS solution?